# Windows Scaling Algorithm

Tags: windows-8.1, display-settings, high-dpi

When Windows scales a window the result is foggy (shown here: [Text is blurry on normal-DPI external display with Windows 8.1 and high-DPI laptop display](https://superuser.com/questions/823645/windows-8-1-on-high-dpi-laptop-display-and-normal-dpi-external-display) ).  What algorithm does Windows use to do window scaling?  Is there a way to change it?

Comment: your link gives the exact answer.

Comment: I meant something like bilinear interpolation.